# Can someone provide a CorsPolicy implementation with an explicit Origins list?

Tags: signalr, cors, owin

### Referring to the [SignalR Hubs API Guide](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain)

indicates the following information in the configuration comments:

```
// Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
// By default this will allow all origins. You can 
// configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
// providing a cors options with a different policy.
map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

however, the Origins property of System.Web.CorsPolicy has a private setter, no constructor that allows origins to be injected, and no exposed setter method.  With regards to the Origins list, it seems to only expose an "AllowAllOrigins" property and then a useless Origins getter that is only reflecting out the empty List that is constructed during CorsPolicy construction.

---

Of particular note, the default
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
setting is entirely incoherent. By its own tooltip, it is "A policy that allows all headers, all methods, any origin, and supports credentials."

```
A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true
```

My configuration is currently the "stupid simple" SignalR config

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{                
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

Can anyone provide a Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware example that would reimplement the "AllowAll" Options with an explicit whitelist for Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at [the source](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Cors/CorsOptions.cs) for `CorsOptions.AllowAll`? It shows how the `CorsOptions` is created. You could do something like

```cs
var policy = new CorsPolicy
{
    AllowAnyHeader = true,
    AllowAnyMethod = true,
    AllowAnyOrigin = false, // False by default, just left it here.
    SupportsCredentials = true
};

policy.Origins.Add("http://foo.example.com");

app.UseCors(new CorsOptions
{
    PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
    {
        PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(policy)
    }
});
```

As you can see, you set the `PolicyResolver` property, which is a `Func<IOwinRequest, Task<CorsPolicy>>`. Based on the `IOwinContext` (for the current request), you need to return a [`CorsPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.cors.corspolicy(v=vs.118).aspx) (also, see [its source](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Cors/CorsPolicy.cs)). This should have the properties you need to fine tune your policy. The list properties have private setters (probably to avoid potential `null` pointers), but they're all initialized in the default constructor, so you should be able to add to them.

Comment: Thanks for the sample; the source for CorsPolicy indicates that the Origins setter is private.  Is there an alternative for specifying Origins?

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. The setter is private, but you can still add to the list. See the updated answer :)

Comment: Thanks for this too - one suggestion is you could create the CorsPolicy just once outside of the PolicyResolved.

Comment: I just realized that I hadn't accepted your post as the answer to my question. Fixed