# Cross-Origin Requests WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I was reading [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet....](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) about Security to prevent AJAX requests to another domain and makes me wonder, if I enable this, I would be able to make request from my Android Client? Cu'z it seems that anything outside of that domain, can't be requested. Is that it? Thanks!

Would be something like:

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
        using (IUserRepository _repository = new UserRepository(new Data.DataContexts.OAuthServerDataContext()))
        {
            var user = _repository.Authenticate(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making the request from another *domain* then you will need to set up an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. You can use `*` if you aren't concerned about security but it's best to specify only the domains you know will need access.

Non-browser-based clients may not necessarily send the Origin header (e.g. Postman) in which case you likely won't need to worry about setting up CORS.

That documentation you linked is a good start. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657965/8005276) provides a good basic example if you want to set up access globally rather than a per-controller basis.

Comment: So, I could setting up the Access-Control in one Action(SaveUsers) and it would be fine with Non-browser client right? Thanks!

Comment: What I'm saying is you may not need CORS for non-browser clients in the first place. Try it without and if it doesn't work then add it in for whatever domain(s) you need.